# onTouch listener call for a layout is triggering in Android 6.0 but its not getting triggered in Android 10 (Accessibility mode)

Tags: android, mobile, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have a code to capture touch events on a clickable FrameLayout.

When I turn on accessibility mode this touch event is not getting triggered in Android 10.

Same code works in Android 6.

Can someone point out the issue here?

Comment: Hi there - just have a few clarifying questions - 
By "Accessibility Mode", do you mean TalkBack? 
What gesture are you using on each system - a double tap to tap?
How is the click event registered?

Comment: yes. @QuintinBalsdon in talkback mode the layouts which already have a touch listener not getting triggered.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code?

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon I think this is the issue I am facing - Double tap considers as click (so touch events wil get affected)https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#a11y